# Gravar option selecionada em um input text que possui "data-role='tagsinput' "

Tags: php, javascript, html

**Resultado esperado:**

as opções que o usuário tem é de inserir os números do centro de custo manualmente e de selecionar em um select o ct custo desejado. Cada vez que o usuário selecionar um ct custo este deve aparecer no campo a esquerda como mostrado na imagem, o mesmo deve ocorrer se ele digitar manualmente no campo da esquerda e ao final pressionar a tecla enter ou vírgula.

[image: resultado esperado]

**Como está funcionando agora:**

Se inserir os valores manualmente eles aparecem no campo como na imagem mostrada acima de forma instantânea (do jeito que deve ser), porém ao inserir os valores pelo select, os valores não aparecem instantaneamente no campo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aparecem somente após realizar uma ação submit:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Montagem do input**

```
//estou usando para aparacer as tags azuis no input text
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>



<td colspan="2"><label for="iCtCusto">Centro de custo:</label>
<input type="text" name="nCtCusto" id="iCtCusto" data-role="tagsinput" value="<?
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($ctCusto); $i++) {                                                                                                       
    echo $ctCusto[$i] . ",";                                                                                                
  }                                                                                                  ?>">

<script>
  var input = [];
  function adicionar() {
  input.push(document.getElementById("iVerCtCusto").value);
  document.getElementById("iCtCusto").value = input;
  }
</script>
<select name="nVerCtCusto" id="iVerCtCusto" onchange="adicionar()" style="padding: 0.2em 0.0em 0.3em; width: 200px">
  <? for ($i = 0; $i < $qtCusto; $i++) { ?>
  <option value="<? echo $cdCentroCustoOption[$i] ?>">
  <?
  echo $cdCentroCustoOption[$i];
  echo $dsCentroCustoOption[$i]
  ?>
  /option>
  <? } ?>
</select>
</td>
```

**O que eu quero**

a cada vez que o usuário selecionar um option, que este apareça na tela na mesma hora

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do tagsinput a melhor forma de adicionar uma nova tag é utilizando a função `.tagsinput('add', <value>)`

E para utilizar essa função você deve obter o elemento a partir do jQuery utilizando `$('#nCtCusto')`

Veja o exemplo abaixo

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- input -->

<input type="text" name="nCtCusto" id="iCtCusto" data-role="tagsinput" value="tag1,tag2">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
  const iCtCustoEl = $('#iCtCusto');
  let count = 1;

  function addOption(tag) {
    // adiciona a nova tag
    iCtCustoEl.tagsinput('add', tag);
  }

  // adiciona 3 tags com um intervalo de 1 segundo entre elas
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    addOption('teste' + count);

    count++;

    if (count > 3) {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, 1000)
</script>
```